# How to determine if a MySQL query is valid?

Tags: mysql

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079625/mysql-join-left-help) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080654/mysql-help-in-select-multi-tables).

With the answers above, I have made this query, is it valid? If not, how can I correct it?

```
SELECT *,
 FROM TABLE_2 t
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT IF(column1 = 'smith', column2, column1)       
 FROM TABLE_1 a
 WHERE 'smith' IN (a.column1, a.column2)
        AND a.status = 1              
                AND ( 'smith' IN (t.column1, t.column2)
               )
```

Comment: The below answer makes it seem this question was rather too broad even when it was asked, so it makes sense for it now to be put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, the comma after `select *` does not belong.

Second, you alias your tables (`table_2 t` and `table_1 a`), but then you don't consistently use the aliases, so you might have issues at run time.  Also from a maintenance perspective, I think most folks prefer to use aliases when declared, and no aliases otherwise.

Third, you do a comparison against cols from the t table in the outer select (`'smith' in (t.column1, t.column2)` ), when that appears unnecessary.  You can just do it in the outer select.  In other words, you can move that terminal paren to before the `AND ('smith'`...

As for whether it works -- I have no idea, since I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Combined, that would leave you with :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE_2 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT IF(a.column1 = 'smith', a.column2, a.column1)       
              FROM TABLE_1 a
              WHERE 'smith' IN (a.column1, a.column2)
              AND a.status = 1)
AND ( 'smith' IN (t.column1, t.column2)
```

Comment: Im confused about SELECT IF(a.column1 = 'smith', a.column2, a.column1). What Im actually trying to do is that, if there is a row, in column1 or column2 having 'smith', then dont select that column, instead select opposite column to that in table1. If you see the first post there you can see table structure and my question again. Hope you can help me sorting out this problem. Thanks - kaash1 1 minutes ago

Comment: @moustafa: what do  you mean by "select opposite column to that in table1" ?

Comment: please have a look at Table 1 and Table 2 in my original post. I want to build a query like: "I want to select all rows from Table 1 where there is smith in column1 or column2. If there is smith in column 1, then select the value from column 2, and if there is smith in column2, then select value in column 1 of the row, then select all the rows from Table 2 which contains that value in column1 or column2 of table 2, which we got by selecting from Table 1"