# Can I redesign this MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

See my last posts:

- [How to determine if a MySQL query is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085796/help-me-in-mysql-query)
- [MySQL join left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079625/mysql-join-left-help)

How can I redesign the tables? I mean which things should be changed? Also, how about if I make two queries as follows?

Query 1:

```
Select from Table one where column1 = 'smith' OR column2 = 'smith' AND status=1
```

Then with help of PHP I get the value

```
if($result['column1']=='smith') { 
 $getValue = $result['column2'] }
else { $getValue = $result['column1'] }
```

Query2:

```
Select from Table2 where column1 = '$getvalue' OR column2 = '$getvalue'
```

Is this is good approach or should I redesign the tables? If I should redesign, can you please tell me what changes I should make?

Comment: This can probably be closed as "opinion-based" or "too broad", especially since it seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can post the CREATE TABLE statements or the goal you are trying to achieve?

It seems like [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) could help a lot - in detail this may be answered with more details about the actual content / semantics...